# Is there a way to convert a yyyy/mm varchar data to date format in snowflake?

Tags: sql, logic, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I convert a yyyy/dd type column to a monthly sort of date. So, I need to convert the quarterly format to a monthly format in snowflake.

For Example: I have a column data like 2021/03 and I have to convert this column data to something like this 2021/01, 2021/02, 2021/03.

If it is like 2021/06 and we need to convert this to 2021/04, 2021/05, 2021/06.

Comment: also show what have you tried

Comment: What does the `03` represent in your `2021/03`? Is that a day, a week (of the year), a month, or a quarter? If it's a day, then is that the day of the year? Like January 3rd?

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: I mean I tried various things like to_date, concat, date_trunc, trim or splitting the column but a new column only gets added. So my ask is I have a column with quarter details like 2021/03(this is yyyy/qq quarter only). I need this to be divided into 3 rows like 2021/01,2021/02,2021/03 (like it's a monthly). @JNevill

Answer (score 1):

```
select TO_DATE(date_column, 'YYYY/MM')
```

Comment: Now that I get it in a proper date format. How can I divide the quarter dates into monthly dates?

Comment: I have used the code you gave above to change the format to 2021/03/01 now.
I want them in separate rows if one row is 2021/3. I need it to be
2021/1
2021/2
2021/3 in 3 different rows.
Can we do this.?

Comment: post it as a separate questions then

Comment: Posted it @trillion

Answer (score 1):

It may help to have a calendar table in your environment to deal with more complicated date conversions like this. An example of what this table may look like is in this CTE below. The SELECT statement following converts a string date of format `YYYY/QQ` of `'2021/03'` to `YYYY/MM`

```
WITH calendar AS
(
    SELECT 
        dateadd('DAY', seq4(), '2000-01-01'::DATE) as calendar_date,
        MONTH(calendar_date) as month_of_year,
        QUARTER(calendar_date) as quarter_of_year,
        YEAR(calendar_date) as year_of_calendar,
        DAY(calendar_date) as day_of_month,
        WEEK(calendar_date) as week_of_year
    FROM table(generator(rowcount => 365*50))
)
SELECT DISTINCT '2021/03' as YYYYQQ_date,
   year_of_calendar || '/' || LPAD(month_of_year, 2, '0') as YYYYMM
FROM calendar 
WHERE year_of_calendar = strtok(YYYYQQ_date, '/', 1) 
    AND quarter_of_year = strtok(YYYYQQ_date, '/', 2);
```

---

```
2021/07
2021/08
2021/09
```

That's merely an example for turning yyyy/qq into multiple yyyy/mm outputs for that quarter, but this same logic can be applied to any date-part conversion and the calendar table can be customized to hold even organization-specific date things like oddball fiscal periods, company holiday flags, or a business day flag (as an example).

Comment: For this I need to run the select query to get the specified quarter to month. But I have a column with Quarter date need that to be converted to monthly in the same table. The monthly date has to be in rows.

Comment: If you have a single row with a quarter and you need three rows with a month then you will use logic like this to get a RESULT SET that has the data you need. You can use an INSERT statement to write that result set into a table. There is not going to be anyway to do this in a single step. This solves your biggest issue of how to convert a quarter-stored-as-string into multiple months. The rest is just plain-jane CREATE TABLE, INSERT, DELETE, INSERT, DROP what-have-you to move the data around as you need.